# How to optimize code with question operator

Tags: typescript, conditional-operator

I have multiple conditions in my code ! So I am thinking of using the question operator instead of `if() .. else..`. But I didn't understand well this operator.

This my code :

```
if(this.intake.repairdamageInfo.additionalinfo){
  damageObjectModel.price = this.intake.repairdamageInfo.additionalinfo.newPrice;
  damageObjectModel.store = this.intake.repairdamageInfo.additionalinfo.storePurchase;
  damageObjectModel.dayValue = this.intake.repairdamageInfo.additionalinfo.dayValue;
}
else {
  damageObjectModel.price = "";
  damageObjectModel.store = "";
  damageObjectModel.dayValue = "";
}
```

I try it like that but it didn't work:

```
  damageObjectModel.price = this.intake.repairdamageInfo.additionalinfo?.newPrice;
  damageObjectModel.store = this.intake.repairdamageInfo.additionalinfo?.storePurchase;
  damageObjectModel.dayValue = this.intake.repairdamageInfo.additionalinfo?.dayValue;
```

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

I'd destructure and assign the empty string as the default values:

```
const { newPrice = '', storePurchase = '', dayValue = '' } = this.intake.repairdamageInfo.additionalinfo ?? {};
Object.assign(damageObjectModel, { price: newPrice, store: storePurchase, dayValue });
```

The `?? {}` will mean that the whole right-hand side will evaluate to the empty object if `additionalInfo` is nullish.

Your original code of

```
damageObjectModel.price = this.intake.repairdamageInfo.additionalinfo?.newPrice;
```

doesn't work because `?.` optional chaining will evaluate to `undefined` if the chain fails, not to the empty string.